# app starting from a deep link overlapping the app with that link

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an app that, when a user sign up, sends an email for activation. When the user taps that link my app starts overlapping the mail app instead of opening or bringing to front the one that the user used to sign up. Is there a way for the link to open or brings to front the one that the user used?